# Datatable : Serverside global search does not send value in "search[value][0]"

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

I have Datatable with server-side (MVC.net) paging, sorting, column filter and global search as follows

Html code

```
    <table id="Grid" class="dataTable table table-striped table-bordered " style="width: 100% !important">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Name2</th>
            <th>name3</th>
            <th>name4</th>
            <th>name5</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>last name</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
                <th> <input class="form-control texts" type="text" placeholder="Filter Name" id="filter0" maxlength="180" /></th>
                <th> <input class="form-control texts" type="text" placeholder="Filter Host" id="filter1" maxlength="180" /></th>
                <th> <select class="form-control selects" id="filter2">
                    <option value="select">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">2</option> 
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select> </th>
                <th>
                    <select class="form-control selects" id="filter3">
                        <option value="select">Select</option>
                        <option value="1">true</option>
                        <option value="2">false/option>
                    </select>
                </th>
                <th><select class="form-control selects" id="filter4">
                    <option value="select">Select</option> 
                    <option value="True">True</option>
                    <option value="false">False</option>
                    </select> 
                </th>
                <th>
                    <select class="form-control selects" id="filter5">
                        <option value="select">Select</option>
                        <option value="True">True</option>
                        <option value="false">False</option>
                    </select>
                </th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    <div class='input-group date col-xs-9' id="datepicker2">
                        <input class="form-control datepicker texts" type="text" placeholder="Filter Key expiration date" id="filter8" maxlength="10" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="ebsi-icon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs pull-right">
                         <input id="btnColumnFilters" class="datatable-action btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-secondary" type="button" value="Filter"/>
                        <input id="btnClearColumnFilters" class="datatable-action btn-sm btn btn-grey btn-secondary" type="button" value="Clear"/>
                    </div> 
                </th>
            </tr>
        <tfoot>
    </table>
```

javascript code :

```
var ConfigTable = $('#Grid')
                .on('preXhr.dt', function(e, settings, data) {
                    $(".alert").hide(); // hide any alerts
                })
                .DataTable({
                    autoWidth: true,
                    lengthChange: false,
                    responsive: true,
                    searching: true,
                    ordering: true,
                    paging: true,
                    pageLength: 10,                      
                    serverSide: true,
                    order: [[0, "asc"]],
                    ajax: {
                        url: "/controller/action",
                        type: "POST",
                        datatype: "json",
                        error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {

                        },
                        data: function(d) {
                            return $.extend({},
                                d,
                                {
                                });
                        }
                    },
                    columns: [
                        { "data": "Name", "name": "Name", "autoWidth": true, "searchable": true },
                        { "data": "Name2", "title": "Name2", "name": "Name2", "autoWidth": true, "searchable": true }.....
                    ]
                });
```

Column filter on button click

```
 //send column filter data on button click
        $("#btnColumnFilters").click(function() {
            filterColumns.map(function (key, value) {
                ConfigTable = ConfigTable.column(key).search($("#filter" + key).val());
            });
            ConfigTable.draw();
        });
```

//server side search only when user hits enter or previous input has been cleared

```
$('#Grid_filter input').unbind();
$('#Grid_filter input').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || $(this).val() == "") {
        // clear all filter selection 
        resetColumnFilters();
        //apply filters
        ConfigTable.columns().search(this.value).draw();
    }
});
```

server-side code

```
    [HttpPost]
            public JsonResult action(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
            {
//globla filter                  
 var search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];
                  // column filter  
 var Name = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[0][search][value]")[0];        

            }
```

but I am not getting global search value in "Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0]" on the server side. it always comes as an empty string. what might be the issue, please help.

I am using 1.10.2 version of datatable plugin.

**Update 1:**

Checked in network tab of firebug for ajax request, empty string is being sent for each request for search parameter, even if search value is there

search[value] : ""

**Update 2:** 
If I remove code to send global filter value only when enter is hit, it sends the search value to server

**Update 3:**
alert on this.value gives a value but
ConfigTable.columns().search(this.value).draw(); does not send value to server

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with any of the tags you've added. If not, you might want to change the tags to get better help

Comment: Thanks Darren, but it's related to jquery data table plugin. I am not sure about using any other tags.

Comment: Hard to tell... Could we get a console.log(d) in your data function?

Comment: @amol you said: `but I am not getting global search value in "Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0]" on the server side. it always comes as an empty string.` Is that not your problem? That's nothing to do with dataTables

Comment: Not sure if just a typo but you have a space in this (after ConfigTable) which will break it `ConfigTable .column(key).search($("#filter" + key).val())`

Comment: @Darren.  I think yes it is  ConfigTable 
       .columns()
       .search(this.value)
       .draw(); should send this value to server

Comment: There shouldn't be any spaces in there

Comment: @amol There should be no spaces

Comment: @all yes updated. it was typo while writing the question

Comment: checked in params for ajax request. always following value is being sent even if search criteria is added  search[value]:""

Comment: If I remove code to send global filter value only when enter is hit, it sends the search value to server

Comment: Hello @amol where is resetColumnFilters code?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. removed columns() while sending global filter

```
$('#Grid_filter input').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || $(this).val() == "") {
        // clear all filter selection 
        resetColumnFilters();
        //removed columns()
        ConfigTable.search(this.value).draw();
    }
});
```